# Using an array for input to while loop

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

This `while` loop works perfectly:

```
while read -r line
    do
        eval ${line}
    done < "${FILE}"
```

However, if I try to use an array for input, it fails.

```
while read -r line
    do
        eval ${line}
    done < "${array[@]}"
```

Is it just not possible, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: Shell redirection syntax *only* shuffles file descriptors around -- changing which file handles are open on which descriptors. It doesn't do any other kind of magic, such as making variable contents available as file-like objects.

Comment: For that you need *different* syntax (though generally, transforming an array into a stream isn't a good idea -- the only way to represent arbitrary array contents unambiguously would be to make the stream NUL-delimited; that's doable, with, say, `done < <(printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"`, and then `while IFS= read -r -d '' item`, but... *why* do that rather than iterate over the array directly?).